# SOLR html content not getting indexed

Tags: html, solr, indexing

I am trying to index xml data in SOLR but it seems that the HTML content inside a tag does not get indexed. I am getting the title and data from the xml but not the description properly. For description I am only getting "testing via" but not the text "Acuity" within tags. Please help!!! The configurations are below.

Actual xml content:

```
<class id="500052442">

    <item>
        <link>1</link>
        <title>Test class1</title>
        <description>testing via <b>Acuity</b></description>
        <date>2013-03-23T23:09:23Z</date>
    </item>

    <item>
        <link>2</link>
        <title>Test class2</title>
        <description>testing via <b>Acuity</b></description>
        <date>2013-03-24T23:09:23Z</date>
    </item>

</class>
```

dataconfig.xml

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="URLDataSource" />
    <document>
        <entity name="slashdot" url="http://localhost:8983/solr/xmls/500052442.xml"
                processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
                forEach="/class/item">

            <field column="link" xpath="/class/item/link" />
            <field column="title" xpath="/class/item/title" />
            <field name="description" column="description" xpath="/class/item/description/text()" />
            <field column="date" xpath="/class/item/date" dateTimeFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" />            
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

schema.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!--
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
-->

<!--  
 This is the Solr schema file. This file should be named "schema.xml" and
 should be in the conf directory under the solr home
 (i.e. ./solr/conf/schema.xml by default) 
 or located where the classloader for the Solr webapp can find it.

 This example schema is the recommended starting point for users.
 It should be kept correct and concise, usable out-of-the-box.

 For more information, on how to customize this file, please see
 http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml
-->

<schema name="rss" version="1.1">
  <!-- attribute "name" is the name of this schema and is only used for display purposes.
       Applications should change this to reflect the nature of the search collection.
       version="1.1" is Solr's version number for the schema syntax and semantics.  It should
       not normally be changed by applications.
       1.0: multiValued attribute did not exist, all fields are multiValued by nature
       1.1: multiValued attribute introduced, false by default -->

  <types>
    <!-- field type definitions. The "name" attribute is
       just a label to be used by field definitions.  The "class"
       attribute and any other attributes determine the real
       behavior of the fieldType.
         Class names starting with "solr" refer to java classes in the
       org.apache.solr.analysis package.
    -->

    <!-- The StrField type is not analyzed, but indexed/stored verbatim.  
       - StrField and TextField support an optional compressThreshold which
       limits compression (if enabled in the derived fields) to values which
       exceed a certain size (in characters).
    -->
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>

    <!-- boolean type: "true" or "false" -->
    <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>

    <!-- The optional sortMissingLast and sortMissingFirst attributes are
         currently supported on types that are sorted internally as strings.
       - If sortMissingLast="true", then a sort on this field will cause documents
         without the field to come after documents with the field,
         regardless of the requested sort order (asc or desc).
       - If sortMissingFirst="true", then a sort on this field will cause documents
         without the field to come before documents with the field,
         regardless of the requested sort order.
       - If sortMissingLast="false" and sortMissingFirst="false" (the default),
         then default lucene sorting will be used which places docs without the
         field first in an ascending sort and last in a descending sort.
    -->    


    <!-- numeric field types that store and index the text
         value verbatim (and hence don't support range queries, since the
         lexicographic ordering isn't equal to the numeric ordering) -->
    <fieldType name="integer" class="solr.IntField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.LongField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="float" class="solr.FloatField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="double" class="solr.DoubleField" omitNorms="true"/>


    <!-- Numeric field types that manipulate the value into
         a string value that isn't human-readable in its internal form,
         but with a lexicographic ordering the same as the numeric ordering,
         so that range queries work correctly. -->
    <fieldType name="sint" class="solr.SortableIntField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="slong" class="solr.SortableLongField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="sfloat" class="solr.SortableFloatField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="sdouble" class="solr.SortableDoubleField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>


    <!-- The format for this date field is of the form 1995-12-31T23:59:59Z, and
         is a more restricted form of the canonical representation of dateTime
         http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime    
         The trailing "Z" designates UTC time and is mandatory.
         Optional fractional seconds are allowed: 1995-12-31T23:59:59.999Z
         All other components are mandatory.

         Expressions can also be used to denote calculations that should be
         performed relative to "NOW" to determine the value, ie...

               NOW/HOUR
                  ... Round to the start of the current hour
               NOW-1DAY
                  ... Exactly 1 day prior to now
               NOW/DAY+6MONTHS+3DAYS
                  ... 6 months and 3 days in the future from the start of
                      the current day

         Consult the DateField javadocs for more information.
      -->
    <fieldType name="date" class="solr.DateField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>


    <!-- The "RandomSortField" is not used to store or search any
         data.  You can declare fields of this type it in your schema
         to generate psuedo-random orderings of your docs for sorting 
         purposes.  The ordering is generated based on the field name 
         and the version of the index, As long as the index version
         remains unchanged, and the same field name is reused,
         the ordering of the docs will be consistent.  
         If you want differend psuedo-random orderings of documents,
         for the same version of the index, use a dynamicField and
         change the name
     -->
    <fieldType name="random" class="solr.RandomSortField" indexed="true" />

    <!-- solr.TextField allows the specification of custom text analyzers
         specified as a tokenizer and a list of token filters. Different
         analyzers may be specified for indexing and querying.

         The optional positionIncrementGap puts space between multiple fields of
         this type on the same document, with the purpose of preventing false phrase
         matching across fields.

         For more info on customizing your analyzer chain, please see
         http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters
     -->

    <!-- One can also specify an existing Analyzer class that has a
         default constructor via the class attribute on the analyzer element
    <fieldType name="text_greek" class="solr.TextField">
      <analyzer class="org.apache.lucene.analysis.el.GreekAnalyzer"/>
    </fieldType>
    -->

    <!-- A text field that only splits on whitespace for exact matching of words -->
    <fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <!-- A text field that uses WordDelimiterFilter to enable splitting and matching of
        words on case-change, alpha numeric boundaries, and non-alphanumeric chars,
        so that a query of "wifi" or "wi fi" could match a document containing "Wi-Fi".
        Synonyms and stopwords are customized by external files, and stemming is enabled.
        Duplicate tokens at the same position (which may result from Stemmed Synonyms or
        WordDelim parts) are removed.
        -->
    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        -->
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>


    <!-- Less flexible matching, but less false matches.  Probably not ideal for product names,
         but may be good for SKUs.  Can insert dashes in the wrong place and still match. -->
    <fieldType name="textTight" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" >
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <!-- This is an example of using the KeywordTokenizer along
         With various TokenFilterFactories to produce a sortable field
         that does not include some properties of the source text
      -->
    <fieldType name="alphaOnlySort" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
      <analyzer>
        <!-- KeywordTokenizer does no actual tokenizing, so the entire
             input string is preserved as a single token
          -->
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!-- The LowerCase TokenFilter does what you expect, which can be
             when you want your sorting to be case insensitive
          -->
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <!-- The TrimFilter removes any leading or trailing whitespace -->
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
        <!-- The PatternReplaceFilter gives you the flexibility to use
             Java Regular expression to replace any sequence of characters
             matching a pattern with an arbitrary replacement string, 
             which may include back refrences to portions of the orriginal
             string matched by the pattern.

             See the Java Regular Expression documentation for more
             infomation on pattern and replacement string syntax.

             http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.6.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html
          -->
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
                pattern="([^a-z])" replacement="" replace="all"
        />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <!-- since fields of this type are by default not stored or indexed, any data added to 
         them will be ignored outright 
     --> 
    <fieldtype name="ignored" stored="false" indexed="false" class="solr.StrField" /> 

    <fieldtype name="html" stored="true" indexed="true" class="solr.TextField">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        -->
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldtype>

 </types>


 <fields>
   <!-- Valid attributes for fields:
     name: mandatory - the name for the field
     type: mandatory - the name of a previously defined type from the <types> section
     indexed: true if this field should be indexed (searchable or sortable)
     stored: true if this field should be retrievable
     compressed: [false] if this field should be stored using gzip compression
       (this will only apply if the field type is compressable; among
       the standard field types, only TextField and StrField are)
     multiValued: true if this field may contain multiple values per document
     omitNorms: (expert) set to true to omit the norms associated with
       this field (this disables length normalization and index-time
       boosting for the field, and saves some memory).  Only full-text
       fields or fields that need an index-time boost need norms.
     termVectors: [false] set to true to store the term vector for a given field.
       When using MoreLikeThis, fields used for similarity should be stored for 
       best performance.
   -->

    <field name="source" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="source-link" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" />

    <field name="subject" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="title" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="link" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="description" type="html" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="creator" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" />
    <field name="item-subject" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <field name="date" type="date" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <field name="slash-department" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <field name="slash-section" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <field name="slash-comments" type="sint" indexed="true" stored="true" />

    <field name="all_text" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
    <copyField source="source" dest="all_text" />
    <copyField source="subject" dest="all_text" />
    <copyField source="title" dest="all_text" />
    <copyField source="description" dest="all_text" />
    <copyField source="creator" dest="all_text" />
    <copyField source="item-subject" dest="all_text" />
 </fields>

 <!-- Field to use to determine and enforce document uniqueness. 
      Unless this field is marked with required="false", it will be a required field
   -->
 <uniqueKey>link</uniqueKey>

 <!-- field for the QueryParser to use when an explicit fieldname is absent -->
 <defaultSearchField>all_text</defaultSearchField>

 <!-- SolrQueryParser configuration: defaultOperator="AND|OR" -->
 <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>

</schema>
```

Comment: Does any one have any clue? I feel like ripping hair of my head!! I have been trying this for so long but with no result!! Please help..

Comment: What do you mean by "getting"?  You not getting what you want as in not able to search as you anticipated, or the stored data returned from queries doesn't look like you expect?  An example would help (you provide an example input, but what does the incorrect output look like).

Comment: The incorrect output is mentioned in my question. When I query for all results, the <description> tag renders the value: "testing via" and not "testing via <b>Acuity</b>" which is actually expected. I have even tried setting the "flatten" attribute on the field definition to true but then it gives me "testing via Acuity" which means it removes the tags.
What I want is the search to return this: <description>testing via <b>Acuity</b></description> but instead it either gives me <description>testing via </description> or <description>testing via Acuity</description>.
Can you help out?

Comment: Your XPath is selecting the `text()` that is a child of `description`, which is just "testing via". The `description` element has two child nodes, the text() node "testing via" and the `<b>` element. Have you tried `/class/item/description` or `/class/item/description/node()`?

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on this thing and it is not straight forward as you look in that. But I have question for you. Those XML files are on same server or those are in different server? I have did this using the nutch and solr. you need to install nutch and and configure with solr. I have asked this question already but didn't got the solution and I have figure out by myself.

for reference here is the link of my question.

[How can I do indexing XML files stored on other server in solr4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489450/how-can-i-do-indexing-xml-files-stored-on-other-server-in-solr4)

[How can I do indexing .html files in SOLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711415/how-can-i-do-indexing-html-files-in-solr)

If you need details of installation and configuration of nutch please let me know. I will provide you in another comment.

If you figure out any direct method in SOLR please let me know as well.

Comment: Currently the XML files are on the same server as I am testing on my system but while in production they might be in different server too.

Comment: oh ok. Did you get any luck on indexing XML files?